# My service.ts doesn't return data to component.ts

Tags: angular

My ftp-request.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {FTPRequest} from './ftp-request';
import {Headers, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
@Injectable()
export class FTPRequestService {
    private APIFTPRequestsURL = '../api/APIFTPRequests';

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getFTPRequests(): Promise<FTPRequest[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.APIFTPRequestsURL)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => response.json().data as FTPRequest[])
                .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

My ftp-requests.component.ts

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';
import { FTPRequest } from './ftp-request';
import { FTPRequestService} from './ftp-requests.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'ftp-requests',
    templateUrl: 'app/FTPRequests/ftp-requests.component.html',
    providers: [FTPRequestService]
})
export class FTPRequestsComponent implements OnInit {
    ftprequests: FTPRequest[];
    constructor(private ftpRequestService: FTPRequestService) { }
    getFTPRequests(): void {
        this.ftpRequestService.getFTPRequests().then(ftprequests => this.ftprequests = ftprequests);
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getFTPRequests();
    }
}
```

my ftp-request.ts

```
export class FTPRequest {
    FTPRequestId: number;
    CreatorId: number;
    FTPRequestDate: string;
    FTPURL: string;
    FTPRequestComments: string;
    NickName: string;
}
```

ftp-requests.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>FTP Requests</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table">
            <tr *ngFor="let ftp of ftprequests">
                <td>{{ftp.NickName| capitalize}}</td>
                <td>{{ftp.FTPRequestId}}</td>
                <td>{{ftp.FTPRequestDate}}</td>
                <td>{{ftp.FTPURL}}</td>
                <td>{{ftp.FTPRequestComments}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Web API service works as expected - it returns
[image]

And the web service has been tested with AngularJS - works as expected.

So, my question is: I am getting data from Web API service in JSON format. I can see them in my debug. For some reason my "ftp-requests.component.ts" is not receiving data from ftp-request.service.ts.

Yes, I am importing HttpModule, JsonpModule in my app.module.js.
And my network panel looks OK:
[image]

Can somebody spot the problem?

Comment: Please edit your post and format your code properly. Use code samples (`{}` in the toolbar) rather than JS/HTML/CSS snippets.

Comment: What does `response.json().data` return in your service? Are you getting the expected values there?

Comment: Also, what does the console say? And do you find the expected JSON array in the network panel of the browser dev tools?

Comment: The problem is that I am not getting the expected values. I know that my WEB API returns the json data (I can see them). My angularjs (1x) works with the service just fine. The service return "undefined" to the component.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. When you look at the response in the network panel of your browser. Do you see an object with a field named `data`, that is an array of FTPRequest objects? Or, when you add `console.log(response.json())` in the promise callback, what do you see?

Comment: Response in the network panel - all page components including APIFTPRequests (my Web API call) have status 200. When I click on the APIFTPRequests - I see the info I requested from my test database: [{"FTPRequestId":1,"CreatorId":1,"FTPRequestDate":"1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM","FTPURL":"ftp://fff.com?h=534E1A66-18AD-4F50-B111-9E515AA7694A","FTPRequestComments":"Low jpg quality","NickName":"CreatorNickName1"},...].

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are trying to display `getFTPRequests()` data before it is fetched. Simple `*ngIf` directive will solve all your problems:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>FTP Requests</h1>
<div class="row" *ngIf="ftprequests">
    <table class="table">
        <tr *ngFor="let ftp of ftprequests">
            <td>{{ftp.NickName| capitalize}}</td>
            <td>{{ftp.FTPRequestId}}</td>
            <td>{{ftp.FTPRequestDate}}</td>
            <td>{{ftp.FTPURL}}</td>
            <td>{{ftp.FTPRequestComments}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this changes did't fix the problem. But, thank you. Everything works when I call getFTPRequests(): Promise<FTPRequest[]> {
return Promise.resolve(FTPRequests);
} from my mock-ftp-request:

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in:

```
getFTPRequests(): Promise<FTPRequest[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.APIFTPRequestsURL)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as FTPRequest[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

When I checked the promise callback - "EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
"
I have changed getFTPRequests() to

```
getFTPRequests(): Promise<FTPRequest[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.APIFTPRequestsURL)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as FTPRequest[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Thank you JB Nizet and Stefan Svrkota for your answers!